# Replication stopped working, no errors

Tags: sql-server, ssms, merge-replication

I have a TOP server (SQL Server 2012) with a merge replication to around 4 other servers. 
When I subscribe to the publication, everything is downloaded fine to the subscriber.

The insert of one of the tables synced with the TOP server but not with a different table in the publication. On another server I have none of the inserts making it to the TOP server.

How can I troubleshoot this kind of problem when SQL Server isn't detecting any problems?